# Regex Find and Move

Tags: regex, find, move

I hope you wouldn't mind answering a question about regular expressions:
I want to do a FIND and MOVE from one place to another within the same file. This will apply to hundreds of files at once.
Example FIND from the text below: `Cat1[changing text]Cat2` and MOVE after `Dog1[changing text]Dog2`

Original file:

```
Cat1[variable text]Cat2 [variable text]
Dog1[variable text]Dog2 [variable text]
Cow1[variable text]Cow2 [variable text]
```

Desired result:

```
  [variable text]
Dog1[variable text]Dog2Cat1[variable text]Cat2  [variable text]
Cow1[variable text]Cow2  [variable text]
```

In other words, I'm trying to move the everything with comes between Cat1 and Cat2 to a different location within the same file. The new location in this case is immediately after Dog1...Dog2. Is there a regex which allows for that? Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the pattern of [changing text], what can we expect to be in there?

Comment: Cat1[something something]Cat2 [something] or at a different time it could be Cat1[green blue]Cat2 [orange yellow]

Comment: Please provide actual example of input output

Comment: Whenever it says variable text, it means it's an alphanumerical text that occur within the two words (Cat1 ... Cat2), and it varies from one file to another. The only constant markers are Cat1... Cat2. So in other words Cat1(.*?)Cat2.

Comment: Thank you for the precision, that helps. Although, do provide actual examples of input and output

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can move matched patterns around using `re.sub` and matching groups. The function `re.sub` will replace backreferences, such as `\1`, with the corresponding matching group.

```
import re

text = """Cat1[text1]Cat2[text2]
Dog1[text3]Dog2[text4]"""


new_text = re.sub(
    r'(Cat1.*?Cat2)(.*?)(Dog1.*?Dog2)',
    r'\2\1\3',
    text,
    flags=re.DOTALL)

print(new_text)
# prints:
# [text2]
# Cat1[text1]Cat2Dog1[text3]Dog2[text4]
```

Comment: Thank you Olivier for the code. Is this for Python?

Comment: @user2828890 Oh sorry, I thought you had added the python tag. Yes it is, is that ok for you?

Comment: I'm using Emeditor. But I can install Python if it will do the job.

Comment: @user2828890 Python is a solid language for handling string and it regexp library is very well documented, so it would definitely be a solution that works.

Comment: Great! I just downloaded it. I know I can spend hours learning how to get started with Python, which I will do...  but can you give me just a little guidance. For example, I just downloaded Python 3.6. Now opened it, I get a command prompt with >>>. Waiting for me to enter something. How do I get it process the code you sent me previously? Thank you!

Comment: @user2828890 You would need to write a .py file and execute it from command line with python filename.py. Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) that may help you doing so

Comment: I pasted your code you sent me (except for the last two lines) and I got the printed text with the last two lines. It looks it works great. How do I implement this to actual php files on my desktop.

Comment: @user2828890 Sorry, I thought the question was Python related and that you had basic Python knowledge and setups. I cannot help much more.